# Receive latest packet in udp server - C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, packet

UDP server is receiving packets with the `select` system call. And I want to receive the latest packet from each UDP-client. (I also want to listen to multiple UDP client packets).

The codes of my simple UDP-server:

```
int main(void) {
    int fd;
    int port = 5678;
    char buffer[1024];
    fd_set readfs;
    socklen_t client_length;
    struct timeval timeout_interval;
    struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in6 client_addr;
    int result;
    int recv;
    char client_addr_ipv6[100];

    fd = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    printf(" \e[1m \e[34m ---------------------------------------- \n--------------------  UDP SERVER --------------------\n   \e[39m \e[0m \n");
    printf("Process: \e[34m %d \e[49m Port ..\n", port);

    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("ERR: fd < 0");
    } else {
        memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
        server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        server_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
        server_addr.sin6_port = htons(port);
        memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
        client_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        client_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
        client_addr.sin6_port = htons(port);

        if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))
                >= 0) {
            printf("\e[1m INFO: \e[0m \e[34m Bind success.. \e[39m\n");

        } else {
            printf("Bind.");
            return -1;
        }
        for (;;) {
            FD_ZERO(&readfs);
            FD_SET(fd, &readfs);
            int max_fd = MAX(0, fd);
            timeout_interval.tv_sec = 3;
            timeout_interval.tv_usec = 50000000;

            result = select(max_fd + 1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &timeout_interval);
            //printf("\n %d \t %d \n", result, fd);
            if (result < 0) {
                printf("ERR\n");
            } else if (result == 0) {
                printf("\nTimeout\n");
            } else {
                if (FD_ISSET(fd, &readfs)) {
                    client_length = sizeof(client_addr);
                    if ((recv = recvfrom(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,
                                    (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_length))
                            < 0) {
                        printf("Recv-ERR!");
                        break;
                    }
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(client_addr.sin6_addr), client_addr_ipv6, 100);
                    //printf("Client IP/Port : %s  ",client_addr_ipv6);

                    printf("\n ------------------------------------------ \n");
                    printf("\e[1m Data: \e[0m  \e[32m %.*s \n Client IP/Port : \e[34m %s / %d \n\e[39m", recv, buffer,client_addr_ipv6,ntohs(client_addr.sin6_port));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you mean the last packet that was sent by the other server, you can't tell which one was last because UDP packets are unordered.  You'd have to put some data in the packet yourself to determine which one was "last".

Comment: I mean the last coming packet from each udp-client. So how to do that without put the "last" define in the packet.Can i code the like "this is a lastest packet from this udp client" ? or how can i code like this ?

Comment: How would you expect to know that a packet is the "latest"?

Comment: Can i provide that with remove the buffer for each client ? @dbush i guess i can know "this packet lastest" with date ? Do you advise the another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to have the sender put a sequence number in each packet.  For each packet that is sent out, the sequence number increases by 1.

On the receiver side, you would keep track of the counter of the last packet you received.  If the next packet that comes in has a larger counter, it's the latest.  If it's not larger, it's an older packet and you can handle it in an appropriate manner for your application.

Also, you should rename you `recv` variable to something like `recv_len`.  `recv` is the name of a socket function that would be masked by this variable definition.

Comment: Make sense but, oldest packet doesn't matter for me, so i would like to do without count or sequense the packets. Clearly i mean; The oldest packet doesnt matter and i would like to use in process the lastest one. Also i have a some process in udp server function after recieve packet, then the buffer listen the other packets in the same time. So if my process end the server continue the which one is next packet (from buffer). I want to if process end then buffer must be clear(I must check which client send this packet) and it must be lastest packet in the buffer from the each client.

Comment: @GökhanAyrancıoğlu There's no way to flush the local buffer to get just the last packet in the buffer without reading them all.  If you do two successive reads, you can't tell if the first packet you read was in the buffer by itself or if another is behind it.  You just need to keep reading them.  And if packets arrive out of order, there needs to be something in the packet to tell you that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually i should wrote the packet size and format in the same for each packets. So i will try to read all of them as you said. Then i will split the buffer with that size so i can find with this way which is lastest. Thank you for your help.